# Set value of a variable to region text

Tags: region

I would like to write a script where I can select some text as the region, extract the selected region as a string, modify it, and pass it to another program.

I am playing around with ielm and see that I can call `(yank)` to pull the region string into a register. How would I go about getting the region string into a variable though?

Comment: How about?   `(buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))` or `(buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))`.  To get it into a variable you can use `(setq my-variable (buffer-substring.....)` or let-bind the value to a temporary variable during the relevant function ...  You'll need to set up a test for whether the region is active before using `region-beginning` and `region-end` or else an error will be thrown ....  See the doc-strings for `region-active-p` and `use-region-p`.

Comment: @Drew bare with me - I don't have all the emacs terminology down but basically I have a region active and I would like the text in that region to be in a variable as a string.

Comment: I see what you're saying @Drew, I meant "parameters" as in parameters that will be passed into the other programs - as far as elisp is concerned a string. I'll edit

Comment: It is @Drew. Post an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
(setq your-variable  (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))
```

If you want a command, try this:

```lisp
(defun my-set-var-to-selection (variable beg end)
  "Set VARIABLE to a string with the selected text.
You are prompted for VARIABLE."
  (interactive 
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (intern (completing-read "Variable: " obarray 'boundp t))
             (region-beginning)
             (region-end))
     (error "No selection (no active region)")))
  (set variable (buffer-substring beg end)))
```

If you don't want to require `VARIABLE` to already be a variable (you want to allow any name as a variable) then remove the arguments `'boundp` and `t` from the `completing-read` call.

If you want to use the region text even when the region is not active (no selection) then use just this as the `interactive` spec:

```lisp
(interactive 
  (list (intern (completing-read "Variable: " obarray 'boundp t))
        (region-beginning)
        (region-end)))
```